# BoxPlot figure is not showing( just getting <AxesSubplot:>)

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, boxplot, subplot

I am already having Tkinter(someone said to install a tkinter)

code used:

imports are:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
```

if u want to view the data-set then it is :

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/diabetes.csv")
```

code used to plot boxplot in jupyter notebook

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,20))
sns.boxplot(data = df,ax = ax)
```

[image])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was supposed to add in my import's

```
%matplotlib inline
```